# Delete wp tags from an array correctly

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, tags

I need to remove some tags periodically from my wp table. Right now I'm using this:

```
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE slug = 'tag-to-delete';
```

But I suppose that the way I'm doing this is not correct because I think I must delete also all the relations with the term, right?

Besides, I would need to do this via functions.php by placing the tags inside an array. eg: `$tags_to_delete = tag1, tag2, tag3;`

Is it possible to do this via functions.php? If so, can someone explain me the correct way to do it?

**EDITED: I've managed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091146/delete-wp-tags-from-an-array-correctly#answer-39131824), but this may not be the final solution because I still have some questions:**

1. Is this safe to use?
2. Is the query correct or it can be improved?
3. Is there a way to return the number of deleted tags?
4. Is there any other way to do this?

Please see [my solution bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091146/delete-wp-tags-from-an-array-correctly#answer-39131824) and help making a better answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I got this working and I hope this can be useful to anyone else. Still, I have some questions:

1. Is this safe to use?
2. Is the query correct or it can be improved?
3. Is there a way to return the number of deleted tags?
4. Is there any other way to do this?

   ```
   $all_terms = array( 'tag number one', 'tag number two', );

   foreach ( $all_terms as $term ) {
   $terms = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM $wpdb->terms AS t INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE t.name IN ('".$term."') AND tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' ORDER BY t.name ASC" );

   if( !empty( $terms ) ) {
       $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->term_taxonomy, array( 'term_taxonomy_id' => $terms->term_taxonomy_id ) );
       $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->terms, array( 'term_id' => $terms->term_id ) );
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using WordPress functions to delete them. They will automatically clean up the relationships:

```php
$tag = get_term( $tag_name, $taxonomy );
if ( ! $tag || is_wp_error( $tag ) ) {
    echo 'cant find the tag: ' . $tag_name ;
} else {
    wp_delete_term( $tag->term_id, $taxonomy );
}
```